# How to echo multiple rows with data based on checkbox input?

Tags: php, mysql

Got stuck trying to echo out multiple rows with data based on checkbox input. As of current code it processes data from only one checkbox, no matter how many checkboxes are ticked. Please help!

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {
    $pals .= '<input type="checkbox" name="pal_num[]" value="'
        . $row['pal_num'] . '">' . $row['pal_num'] . '<br>';
}

if ($pal == '') {
    echo '';
} else {
    echo '<form name="get_pal" action="post2.php" method="POST">';
    echo $pals;
    echo '<input type="submit" name="post" value="Go!">';
    echo '</form>';
}
```

**post2.php:**

```
$w = $_POST['pal_num'];
$rrr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_tab WHERE pal_num" . $w[0]);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rrr)) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . '&nbsp' . '</td>';
    echo '<td rowspan="5">' . $row['descr'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><b>' . 'Total weight' . '<b></td>';
    echo '<td>' . '&nbsp' . '</td><td>' . '&nbsp' . '</td></tr>';

    echo '<td>' . '&nbsp' . '</td>';
    echo '<td colspan="3">' . '&nbsp' . '</td>';

    //this part should multiple based on how many checkboxes are ticked.
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['l_num'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['pal_num'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['weight 1'] . '</td><td>' . $row['weight 2'] . '</td></tr>';
}
echo "</table>";
}
```

Comment: Make sure you sanitize `$w[0]` with [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) (and maybe switch to a more modern database API like mysqli or PDO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will work :

```
$w = "'".implode("','",$_POST['pal_num'])."'";
$rrr = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pl_tab WHERE pal_num in (".$w.");");
```

...and may be you forgot a `echo "<table>";` before the `while` :)

Comment: after some tweaking it worked! thank you for helping out a newbie :)